# How to get textarea value into a varaible outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the variable "apry" be equal to the written data in "textarea",

So then i will can get its value into URL?

HTML:

```
<textarea id="post" type="text"></textarea>
<a onclick="location.href = 'http://localhost/arany/?i=' + apry + '';">Reload</a>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#post').keyup(function() { 
    var apry = document.getElementById('post').value; 
  }); 
})
```

Comment: Just write the entire click handler in javascript or use jquery for it. Or at least use onclick="someFunctionName()". Inline click handlers do not have access to variables defined inside a different function.

Comment: First of all, anchors have an `href` attribute that does exactly what your `onclick` function does. So, just change that `href` attribute in your `keyup` handler.

Comment: Note you should be uri encoding that value also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually setting the value of apry, but the problem is you then aren't doing anything with it, including not updating your DOM element. You would need the following instead :

```js
$(document).on("keyup", "#post", function() {
$("#theLink").attr("href", "http://localhost/arany/?i=" + $("#post").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="post" type="text"></textarea>
<a id="theLink" href="#">Reload</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres no need for a global variable in this case. You can just listen for the `click` event on the reload button:

```
<textarea 
id="post" type="text"></textarea>
<button id="reload">
Reload
```

```
$(document).ready( function() { 
    $('#reload').click(function() {
        location.href = 'http://localhost/arany/?i=' + 
        $('#post').val(); 
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4j0fohr5/1/

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require it would make more sense to invert the logic. Instead of creating and updating a variable which has the value of the `textarea` as it's typed in to, simply have an event handler which reads the value from the `textarea` when the `a` is clicked. This has the benefit of avoiding an unnecessary global variable. Try this:

```
<textarea id="post" type="text"></textarea>
<a href="#" class="id">Reload</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#reload').click(function() { 
    location.assign('/arany/?i=' + $('#post').val()); 
  }); 
});
```

One thing to note here is that you will have to be careful with line breaks in the value.

Alternatively if you did want to update the `href` of the `a` as the `textarea` is typed in to you could use `prop()` to do that inside an `input` event handler:

```
<textarea id="post" type="text"></textarea>
<a href="/arany/?" id="reload">Reload</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#post').on('input', function() { 
    $('#reload').prop('href', '/arany/?i=' + $(this).val()); 
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to add the textarea content as a query string `"i"` parameter when you click the `"Reload"` button.

For that purpose you only need an input text field instead of a textarea, since the URL does not support line break characters.

Also, you don't need to update the `"i"` every time you change the text, realize that you need that value just when you click the `"Reaload"` button.

So, here is what I propose to you to solve your problem:

```
<input type="text" id="post"></textarea>
<a onclick="goToLocation();">Reload</a>

function goToLocation(){
    apry = window.document.getElementById('post').text();
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost/arany/?i=' + apry;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var apry = null;        
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#post').keyup(function() { 
    apry = document.getElementById('post').value; 
  }); 
})
```

This should work for you